# SQL Server Named Instance is not listening on Port 1434

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, connectivity, tcpip

We just installed SQL Server 2016 on a Windows 2016 server.  I am having issues connecting to the Named Instance of that server. I have noticed that the server isn't listening on port 1434 either.  Normally we would see it in log as:

```
Server is listening on [XX.XX.XX.XX <ipv4> 1434>
```

But the only thing I see in the logs are:

```
Server is listening on [ 127.0.0.1 <ipv4> 63229].
Server is listening on [ ::1 <ipv6> 63229].
```

I can seem to connect to this named instance other than on the local server.  We have apps running that will hit this Named Instance but it seems like we are having issues connecting.

I also did a `netstat -ao | findstr /I "processID"` and I couldn't see the 1434 ports.  I had configured my TCP/IP to use the TCP Port 1434 for my IP but it's still not working.

Any ideas why it's not listening on 1434?

I checked in Configuration Manager and everything looked fine.  TCP/IP was enabled and SQL service restarted.  It doesn't seem to be listening on that port when it starts up.

The SQL Browser service is turned on. The TCP Port 1434 is assigned to the IP but the TCP Dynamic Ports and TCP Port is blank in the `IPALL`.

Maybe the question is how is the named instance supposed to be set up?  This was to replace an old server that was running SQL 2012 and that server had it set this way and it's been running fine.  So I copied the same setting and we can't seem to connect to the named instance.

Comment: Also check dynamic port in Config Manager.  If dynamic ports are on, the name distance will snatch a port up on its first start, then try to reuse it on all subsequent restarts.  If it's taken by another process, it will roll on to a new one.  You may want that turned off if you are trying to force a certain port number

Comment: By what you posted, TCP dynamic ports are used and you can see it is listening on port 63229. I'm with @sp_BlitzErik to check SSCM and see what it says both on enabled protocols and on tcp ports used.

Comment: isn't 1434 used by the DAC? possibly the named instance is reverting to dynamic port because DAC took 1434

Comment: As a debugging step, I'd try configuring it to use a different port (54321, maybe), and confirm connectivity.

Comment: 1434 is the SQL Browser. It's quite possible that the browser wasn't running in your old 2012 install, so your 2012 instance could take that port. The browser is running in your new install so it couldn't. How did you connect in the old install? Did you supply a port number? The way it's meant to be set up depends on how you used to connect (and whether you want to keep connecting that way). Its is certainly non-standard to force it to port 1434. Can you supply a sample connection string from your old setup and indicate whether you can/will change this going ahead?

Comment: SQL Browser uses UDP port 1434, not TCP.

Answer (score 4):

Some additional investigation is needed here. First, it is possible that you are filtering out too much of the `netstat` output in your `findstr` filter. Instead of "processID", check for the port number using ":1434". Also, using the `-q` switch instead of `-a` might be better as it will show bound, nonlistening ports. For example:

```
netstat -qof | findstr ":1434"
```

OR, if you start the command prompt as an administrator, you can add the `-b` switch to print out the name of program associated with each process (saves the step of needing to map the Process ID to the program). When doing this, the output of each entry is on 2 lines, so you won't see the additional info if you use `findstr` as those lines will never have the matching string. Instead, just pipe to `more` as follows:

```
netstat -qofb | more
```

Now, using `netstat` is handy to research to see if a port is in use, but for this issue it is more direct to see what SQL Server thinks is going on, and fortunately there are some views that have the info so you don't need to scan / parse the error log. You should check the following:

- [sys.tcp_endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-tcp-endpoints-transact-sql)
- [sys.dm_tcp_listener_states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-tcp-listener-states-transact-sql)

So just execute the following:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.tcp_endpoints;
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_tcp_listener_states;
```

If the first view, `sys.tcp_endpoints`, shows that "Dedicated Admin Connection" has a `state_desc` other than "STARTED", then there is an issue.

Now, in the second view, `sys.dm_tcp_listener_states`, if you do have "::1" (IP v 6) and/or "127.0.0.1" (IP v 4) for `ip_address` then it is only listening locally (i.e. remote administrative access is OFF). If you instead see "::" (IP v 6) and/or "0.0.0.0" (IP v 4), then remote admin access is ON.

By default remote administrative access is OFF. You can enable it by executing the following (this is *not* an "advanced" option):

```
EXEC sp_configure N'remote admin connections', 1; RECONFIGURE;
```

Answer (score 0):

In General, allow firewall access to the following ports to connect to SQL Server remotely:

**For Default Instances**

- TCP port 1433
- TCP port 1434 (For DAC Connection)

**For Named Instances**

- TCP Port (Whichever port the SQL Server is listening on – Check the Error Log for Port Details)
- UDP Port  1434 (For Browser Services)
- UDP (and TCP) Port on which Dedicated Admin connection is listening (UDP is what worked for me). Check the SQL Server log to note as to on which port was Dedicated admin connection was established:

“Message
Dedicated admin connection support was established for listening locally on port XXXXX”

For Named instances, make sure that the Browser Service is running if the external applications are connecting using the Instance name.

Also note that for Named instances, it is better to configure SQL Server to listen on a static port otherwise firewall management will become difficult as SQL Server will listen on a different port every time it’s restarted.